# Incorrect password at Cardamom Login for Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

Tags: 10.04, login

I installed Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS on a single board computer (namely RoBOard) through a USB. After intallation and reboot, I got into the login page with the word "Cardamom under the Ubuntu logo. I remember the user name and password I set during installation, but those didn't work. It said Authentication Error and Incorrect Login.

Does anyone know what the problem might be??

Answer (score 0):

If you're **SURE** that you remember the correct password, it's an issue with 'PAM'. Check this link: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1702833

And, edit those files using a Ubuntu LiveCD. Set a `root` password on the disk after you log-in using:

`$ sudo passwd root`

Be advised that the password change is lost the next time you use the CD.